# Calculating prime numbers in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to calculate prime numbers in Rust but having some issues. I getting two errors. I am not understanding how the value is returning to the main function.

```
fn main() {
    let x = is_prime(25); //function calling
    println!("{}", x);
}

fn is_prime(n: u32) -> bool {
    let mut result: bool = for a in 2..n {
        result = if n % a == 0 { false } else { true };
    };
    result
}
```

```
error[E0425]: cannot find value `result` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:8:9
  |
8 |         result = if n % a == 0 { false } else { true };
  |         ^^^^^^ not found in this scope
help: possible candidates are found in other modules, you can import them into scope
  |
1 | use futures::future::result;
  |
1 | use tokio::prelude::future::result;
  |

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:7:28
  |
6 |   fn is_prime(n: u32) -> bool {
  |                          ---- expected `bool` because of return type
7 |       let mut result: bool = for a in 2..n {
  |  ____________________________^
8 | |         result = if n % a == 0 { false } else { true };
9 | |     };
  | |_____^ expected bool, found ()
  |
  = note: expected type `bool`
             found type `()`
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are using the variable `result` **while defining it**

```
...
let mut result: bool = for a in 2..n { // declared here
    result = if n % a == 0 { // used here, but it is still not initialized
...
```

You can easily do without the `result` variable, is not necessary:

```
fn is_prime(n: u32) -> bool {
    if n <= 1 {
        return false;
    }
    for a in 2..n {
        if n % a == 0 {
            return false; // if it is not the last statement you need to use `return`
        }
    }
    true // last value to return
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1f93c0a907212674770f52ba13ee07c2)

Comment: The `match` statement is really not needed here; `if n % a == 0 { return false; }` is much simpler and avoids the extra `continue`. The whole function could be `!(2..n).any(|a| n % a == 0)` or `(2..n).all(|a| n % a != 0)`

Answer (score 4):

You have several issues in your code (ignoring that it does not compile):

- you overwrite the result -> imagine `n = 4`. When you divide by 2 you get `result = true`,  but in the next iteration when you divide by 3 you get `result = false`
- if `n<=2` your loop will never be executed, hence what will result be

Instead of trying to use any new piece of syntax, try to write it to be as readable as possible:

```
fn is_prime(n: u32) -> bool {
    let limit = (n as f64).sqrt() as u32;

    for i in 2..=limit {
        if n % i == 0 {
            return false;
        }
    }

    true
}
```

Comment: Explicit `return` statements at the end of a block are non-idiomatic. See the [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55790537/calculating-prime-numbers-in-rust#comment98258615_55790685) which shows how to use iterator methods instead of writing the for loop explicitly.

Comment: That's the thing that annoys me most in Rust - I really hate to be able to do such a simple operation in 2 different ways.

Comment: @SveltinZarev the `return` keyword is necessary so you can break out of a function early while returning a value so I don't see how you could remove it from the language entirely although possibly this could be a compiler warning, "don't use `return` in the final statement/expression of a function"? 